# Is it possible to configure sub-project dependencies in SBT based on a `SettingKey`?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
lazy val customFlag = settingKey[Boolean]("My custom flag")

lazy val depOne    = project ...
lazy val depTwo    = project ...

lazy val myproject = project
  .settings(
    customFlag := false)
  .dependsOn(if (customFlag) depOne else depTwo)
```

The idea being, that I could then use `set customFlag := true` in the sbt console in order to change whether project `myproject` depends on sub-project one or two.

I have a hunch at this point that the answer is that this is not possible. But it would be nice to get confirmation or an alternative to accomplish something similar.

Comment: You might be able to use an environment variable to configure this instead of a setting. Or a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not possible to use setting key in the `dependsOn`.

Comment: Is there an idiomatic way to do this with sbt?